# Need comments on MySQL events

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

CREATE TABLE question(
    qid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    text CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    variation BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    url CHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    expired TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE alternativ(
    aid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    text CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    number_chosen INT,
    qid INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE alternativ
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (qid)
    REFERENCES question(qid);

CREATE EVENT delete_expired
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
    DELETE FROM alternativ WHERE alternativ.qid IN (SELECT qid FROM question WHERE question.expired<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    DELETE FROM question WHERE question.expired < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

My question is: Should this event work with the specified database? I have tried, but it dosen't seem to work. The idea is that the database itself will delete questions that has expired. Help would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify multiple statements within the event body, you will need to wrap them within a compound statement block such as `BEGIN ... END` (in order to make such a command work, one must configure one's client to use an alternative statement delimiter in order that it does not think the first encountered semicolon terminates the `CREATE EVENT` statement—in the mysql command-line tool, one can use the `DELIMITER` command):

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE EVENT ... DO BEGIN
  DELETE  ... ;
  DELETE  ... ;
END ;;

DELIMITER ;
```

That said, one can delete from multiple tables with a single `DELETE` command using the multiple-table syntax:

```
DELETE alternativ, question
FROM   alternativ JOIN question USING (qid)
WHERE  question.expired < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, all that said, you might fare better specifying foreign key constraints that *cascade* record deletions:

```
FOREIGN KEY (qid) REFERENCES question(qid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then, one only need `DELETE` the referenced record (i.e. in the `question` table) and MySQL will delete the referencing records (i.e. in the `alternativ` table) for you.